# NHibernate + MySql Intermittent TimeoutException

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, timeout

I have just migrated my NHibernate app from SQL Server to MySql.  All seems well except I am getting intermittent TimeoutExceptions.  I can find a lot of info about this timeouts with MySql and even [one blog post](http://www.codefin.net/2007/05/hibernate-and-mysql-connection-timeouts.html) about timeouts with Hibernate + MySql + C3PO (whatever that is).  But nothing about how to tweak NHib to stop this problem.  Do you know?

Here is the stack trace:

```
NHibernate.TransactionException: Begin failed with SQL exception ---> System.TimeoutException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception e)
   at MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadOk(Boolean read)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetDatabase(String dbName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.SetDatabase(String dbName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.ChangeDatabase(String databaseName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.GetConnection()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.get_Connection()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.BeginTransaction()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.BeginTransaction()
```

Comment: for now you could put a Timer to do some dummy SELECT, to avoid the timeout?

Comment: Tim did you solve this as I wondering about this more and more...

Answer (score 0):

I run NHibernate on Rackspace cloud with a MYSQL database. I found I was getting timeouts due to the fact that connections were being left semi open due to sleeping. Eventually I was running out of connections and my web site timed out.

In the end I added `Pooling=false;` into my connection string. I am not sure if this is the ultimate fix but it has stopped my problem.

You can check for sleeping connections by using `show processlist` in a MySQL editor...

Comment: Thanks.  Yikes!  Pooling=false?  Are you worried about the performance impact of that?

Comment: Most likely yes, it does depend on use case; however I think there is a bug in the pooling code that marks connections as `sleeping` BUT does not allow them to be woken up thus eventually you run out of connections. Like I said this is not the ultimate fix but it is a workaround for me at least for now.

Comment: Tim have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567097/using-mysqlconnection-in-c-does-not-close-properly