# MySQL Connection will not close

Tags: c#, mysql

This is really simple, all i'm trying to do is fill a datatable, i have everything surrounded by using() and the connection will not dispose/close.  Please help

```
DataTable loginTbl = MySQLProcessing.MySQLProcessor.StoreProcedureDTTable("Login", ParamArgs, "Login");


 public static DataTable StoreProcedureDTTable(string mysqlQuery, List<string> CommandArgs, string queryName)
    {

        DataTable DTTableTable = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlCommand MySQLCommandFunc = new MySqlCommand(mysqlQuery))
        {
            MySQLCommandFunc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (string args in CommandArgs)
            {
                string[] splitArgs = args.Split('|');
                MySQLCommandFunc.Parameters.AddWithValue(splitArgs[0], splitArgs[1]);
            }
            using (MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(MySQLCommandFunc))
            {
                DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
                lock (_object)
                {
                    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysqlCon"].ConnectionString))
                    {
                        MySQLCommandFunc.Connection = con;
                        DataDTTables.Fill(DTTableTable);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        DataTable catchConnectionTable = DTTableTable;
        DTTableTable.Dispose();
        return catchConnectionTable;
    }
```

Comment: Is an exception being thrown?

Comment: nope, runs perfectly just never closes the connection

Comment: Maybe similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567097/using-mysqlconnection-in-c-sharp-does-not-close-properly

Comment: The issue there seems to be that the asker didn't understand .NET connection pooling, the end of the using calls the Close method but that just releases the connection back to the connection pool, it doesn't destroy the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Pooling=False to the connection string

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
      using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysqlCon"].ConnectionString))
      {
           con.open();
           MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(MySQLCommandFunc)
           DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
           MySQLCommandFunc.Connection = con;
           DataDTTables.Fill(DTTableTable);
           con.close();
     }
```

?

Comment: Dan - Nope odesn't close the connection, the connection is actually onped on at DataDTTables.Fill(DTTableTable);, so i'm assuming the MySqlDataAdapter  is holding the connection

Comment: Have you tried con.open and con.close though? Otherwise can't help you.

Comment: Dan - Yes but by default MySqlDataAdapter  tries to open the connection

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to `Pooling=false` are [SqlConnection.ClearPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [SqlConnection.ClearAllPools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods. For more information read: [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)