# C# application creating many connection threads, MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

My C# app is causing atleast 2-3 continuous 'threads connected' as per MySQL Client Connections' tab in Workbench. I still am not able to understand why this is, even after thawing a parallel thread which executes queries, I was only able to bring continuous 'threads connected' down from 4 to 2-3.

I even checked if I am failing to close a connection after a query is executed, couldn't find a missing connection.close(). Anyways wouldn't be sure of it. I checked general log file I could only find 'connect' instances but not a single 'kill/close' instance.

Moreover, as per the command field in the MySQL Client Connections' tab

- *Thread no 1*: Sleeps for 1 sec and then reverts back to 0.
- *Thread no 2*: Sleeps for 30 sec and then reverts back to 0.

I can understand the *Thread no 2* as I have a timer that triggers every 30 sec and in which I run queries.

NOTE: Timer 30 sec event is the only place I run queries and General log file too collaborates this.

However, I fail to understand why 2 or 3 continuous connection threads are created.

**EDIT** (Typical Code I use)

```
internal bool id_exists(int id)  
    {
        bool to_return = false;
        string myconnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);     //Connect to MySql

        string Query = " SELECT * FROM database.table;";
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);     //Command for the database

        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                if (myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetOrdinal("id"))) { continue; }
                if (myReader.GetInt32("id") == pre_id) { to_return = true; break; }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //Incase case of exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error 5: " + ex.Message + "\n\nError loc: " + this.GetType().Name + " : " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "\n\nStack Trace:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        myConn.Close();
        return to_return;
    }
```

**2nd EDIT**: As @PanagiotisKanavos said ADO.Net has connection pooling which causes many connection threads to be created. Most probably variation in connection strings is the culprit for creating multiple connection threads.

I tried adding Pooling = False as per this  [MySQL Connection will not close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472768/mysql-connection-will-not-close?lq=1) link and now at max only one connection thread shots up when I run the C# app. I even noticed that the performance has deteriorated in comparison to Pooling = True.

Now, if anyone could clarify the following doubt it would be very helpful:
Since I need to have different connection string and Connection Pooling is creating many connection threads, it contributes to reaching max_connection limit in no time when using C# app on different machines simultaneously.

Is there any other solution through which I can keep Connection pooling and at the same time avoid going beyond max_connection limit too soon?

Comment: How do you create the connections? Where is the code? Do you close them after using them? Are you sure you aren't seeing the effects of connection pooling (which is a good thing)?. Do you see the connections increasing or do they stay the same as you open/close new connections in code?

Comment: Connection pooling means that ADO.NET keeps and reuses connections when you close them so it doesn't have to create new ones each time. It will only create a new one if the current pooled connections are all in use. You can see the relevant performance counters in the `.NET CLR Data` category (at least for SQL Server). There may be a category specific to your MySQL Connector

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just edited the question with typical code I use. Yes I close the connection after I use. Don't know if I am seeing effects of connection pooling. No, I see constant 2 'threads connected' and a 3rd one intermittently in the MySQL Workbench Client Connections' tab.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In that case won't it affect if my C# app runs on many systems and if the 'threads connected' breaches the max_connection limit which is set to 151?

Comment: Tried the answer given in this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472768/mysql-connection-will-not-close?lq=1)

Adding pooling = False in the connection string seems to solve the issue at the most only 1 'thread connected' . So as you it has to do with ADO.NET connection pooling. It seems to avoid max_connection errors connection pooling needs to disabled right?

Comment: Also after Pooling = False, I noticed in the general log that some extra queries are generated in comparison to Pooling method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myconnection);
```

Use a "using" clause:

```
using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myconnection))
{
...
}
```

With the closing brace *in place* of the "myConn.Close()" line.

I'm not certain it will fix your problem, but it will be better coding.  What the "using" statement does is close and dispose the connection upon exiting the using, regardless of whether there is an exception or not.

Any time you use a class that implements IDispose, such as the SqlConnection class, you should always use that "using" statement to ensure the object gets properly disposed when you are done with it.

Comment: This is far better code but it won't fix what isn't broken. Connection pooling will keep connections for reuse. The OP should also dispose of the command and the reader

Comment: Ok so ADO.NET does not close connection as it is Connection pooling. So what if lets says out of 3 connection threads 2 are asleep and another machine with the same C# code access the server?   

It for sure doesn't close the 2 thread which are asleep but adds another three connection threads.(Checked it) So my question will it not block new connection threads incase the connection threads reaches connection limit? Although most threads would be sleeping